PowerApp Lookup Original Value on Edit
I have a PowerApps SharePoint form that uses cascading lookups.
They work perfectly when creating new records, but whenever editing, the fields always start as blank, which means the user has to reselect a value for every lookup on every edit.
Guessing the problem is since this is a dynamic lookup, the lookup collection is created in the OnSelect event. The field value is stored as static text in SharePoint.
Tried adding ThisItem.'FieldName' to the Default on the DataCard.  Also tried that in the Default on the lookup control.  And tried doing LookUp against the collection, but the collection doesn't actually exist yet, since it is created during OnSelect.
Suggestions on a better approach?

Since you are giving edit control, so you have to load you collections containing dropdowns.

@Sumit: Sorry, I don't understand your recommendation.  What event are you suggesting I use to load the collections?  I can't seem to find a good one that works.
